# Can I inject controller from ASP.NET Core MVC architecture to Blazor components?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, blazor

We have a project based on ASP.NET Core MVC. We started to use some additional filters and pages with Blazor.

Now I have a problem redirecting or navigating to another view (`.cshtml`) page after clicking on the button.

I tried many things but still can't find how to solve this problem.

I'm getting id from the `context.Item.ID` but it never hit the controller site to show edit view.

How should I re-work this controller call / or controller method to show another Edit-view page to return the edit view with the correct id?

Thanks a lot!

```
@inject UploadController _controller
.
.
.

<MudIconButton Size="@Size.Small" Icon="@Icons.Material.Outlined.Edit" OnClick="(()=>EditDoc(context.Item.ID))" />

protected async void EditDoc(int id)
{
    await _controller.DocumentEdit(id);
}
```

Comment: What you're looking for is just a link. Use the `<a>` helper

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically what I found is that I need to use `NavigationManager` with the method `NavigetTo` with the parameter forceLoad = true this is important.
The code looks like this:

```
protected async Task EditDoc(int id)
{
    NavManager.NavigateTo($"/Upload/DocumentEdit/{id}", true);      
}
```

Calling Upload Controller / DocumentEdit method and hereafter thinks what I need just `return View();`